# how to customize evaluation metric in Autogluon?

Tags: machine-learning, parameters, multiclass-classification, autogluon

I want to use the AutoGluon library to find the best model. My problem is a classification problem with 8 classes. I have weights for the correct predictions of the classes, and I want to find the F1 scores multiplied by these weights to determine the best model. How can I set the evaluation metric? For example, for a model, if the F1 scores are [0.2, 0.3, 0., 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0., 0.1], and the weights are as follows:

```
# Define the custom evaluation function
def weighted_f1_score(y_true, y_pred, weights):
    # Calculate the F1 score for each class
    f1_scores = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average=None)
    # Multiply each F1 score by the corresponding weight
    weighted_f1_scores = f1_scores * weights
    # Calculate the total weighted F1 score
    total_weighted_f1_score = np.sum(weighted_f1_scores)
    return total_weighted_f1_score

# Define the weights for each class
weights = {
    0: 0.0385,
    1: 0.0328,
    2: 0.2791,
    3: 0.1812,
    4: 0.0113,
    5: 0.2952,
    6: 0.1614,
    7: 0.0001
}

# Define the custom evaluation function outside of the fit call
custom_eval_metric = lambda y_true, y_pred: weighted_f1_score(y_true, y_pred, weights)

# Train the models using AutoGluon and specify the custom evaluation function
predictor = TabularPredictor(label="LABEL", eval_metric=custom_eval_metric)
predictor.fit(balanced_train_df, time_limit=500)
```

How to customize the evaluation metric in AutoGluon, How to define your own evaluation function and pass it as the eval_metric parameter when training the model?

How to customize the evaluation metric in AutoGluon, How to define your own evaluation function and pass it as the eval_metric parameter when training the model?